# How to control Apple ProMotion FPS in iOS / ARKit?

Tags: swift, retina-display, ios11, arkit

In iOS 11 Beta 1 and 3 the camera and display of ARKit application were operating at 60 FPS, while in iOS 11 Beta 2 both are running at 120 FPS (ProMotion).

Is there any way to control the FPS? I found 120 frames per second much more pleasing for AR applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [preferredFramesPerSecond](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/1621205-preferredframespersecond) property of `ARSCNView` (or `SCNView`).

> SceneKit chooses an actual frame rate that is as close as possible to
>   your preferred frame rate based on the capabilities of the screen the
>   view is displayed on. The actual frame rate is usually a factor of the
>   maximum refresh rate of the screen to provide a consistent frame rate.
>   For example, if the maximum refresh rate of the screen is 60 frames
>   per second, that is also the highest frame rate the view sets as the
>   actual frame rate. However, if you ask for a lower frame rate,
>   SceneKit might choose 30, 20, 15 or some other factor to be the actual
>   frame rate. For this reason, you want to choose a frame rate that your
>   app can consistently maintain. The default value is 60 frames per
>   second.